# Where should question about design review end up on SE?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm currently wondering where should I ask for design review.

Some background : I'm currently doing an internship that concludes my studies, but I ended up in a company where I'm the only developer working on the software part of the company's product (basically, I started from scratch and wrote specifications, designed the software and currently develop the software).

The problem is, I want to improve, but nobody in the company can review what I do and criticize work (unless it's pretty obvious that it doesn't work), and thus I don't really know if my design/implementation choices are correct or not, if I use Qt correctly, etc.

Then, I don't really know where I could ask for advices about my design. I feel that for implementations [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is pretty obvious, but what about design ? Should I ask for advices on codereview as well ? Or [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit ?

(I don't even know if it's the place to ask for that, I'll delete if not).

As suggested in the `site-rec` tag, questions could be :

- Is there a better architecture for this / what are the flaws of my approach ?
- Is there a better way to use signals/slots in Qt than what I did ?
- etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is the one to go to.

> Programmers is a place to ask conceptual questions about software
>   development. <sup>[1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about)</sup>

You will also notice code review has a [[design] tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design)

Comment: "Programmers is more about culture" Hm, what?

Comment: Edited to transfer more meaning

Comment: I don't think you've made it better, see: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: In the future please don't post two answers. You can edit your existing answer then undelete it.

Comment: It was a double post. Notice this answer was deleted.

Comment: @Yannis thank you, I see my mistake now.

Comment: Programmers actually may be a good place to post a design review, please see this post for more information: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/are-design-review-questions-on-topic